# Performance impact of creating large number of threads in C# Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

We are developing an application that needs to perform certain small operations (expression evaluations) very frequently based on changes of parameter values. To perform these small operations, we are creating threads which do evaluation and terminate. My questions is, what is performance impact of creating large number of thread will a very small lifetime. Lets say 100 to 200 threads per second whose lifetime will not last more than one second.

The issue with threadpool is that certain operations had to wait due to unavailability of background threads. That's why switched to creating a new thread when required.

Can anyone share some insight on performance impact in this scenario, and suggest if any better way to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Unless you have 100-200 cores (and the work is CPU bound - which it appears to be), there's absolutely no reason to have that many threads.

Comment: For one thing, there is a cost to _starting_ a new thread from scratch as opposed to grabbing a _warm-ready-to-go_ thread from the .NET thread pool basket of goodness. This cost becomes relatively more expensive if your jobs are quite short (as is in your case)

Comment: @Rob Could coding for a GPU have this use-case?

Comment: Your argument against the tread pool is flawed. Starting a thread for each operation does not make the work finish faster.

Comment: "The issue with threadpool is that certain operations had to wait due to unavailability of background threads." And threads won't magically make your 16 core processor capable of executing 200 operations at the same time. If you have other tasks that may run longer and block your small operations I'd think about a separate thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that creating and destroying threads in .Net is simple, does not mean that the cost of these operations is insignificant. The same thing can be said about the scheduling of threads on processor cores (context switching), so you don't want to overdo these things unless you have the adequate number of cores on your machine.

That been said, I understand that what you are trying to do is already managed by the .Net [TaskScheduler class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . All you have to do, is using it.